# Typescript: проигнорировать неявное использование any при импорте из js-модуля

Tags: typescript

В Typescript-проекте мне нужно импортировать старые js-модули, внутри которых используется module.exports.

Когда я импортирую:

```
import * as httpConnection from '...path...';
```

Компилятор выкидывает ошибку:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '...path...'. '...path...' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

После этого все работает, но мне нужно избавиться от этой ошибки в консоли.

Как мне объяснить компилятору, что импортируемые сущности имеют тип any без использования файла .d.ts?

Спасибо за идеи заранее.